# Is it a good practice to put ResultSet into a nested try-with-resources statement after Java7?

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch, try-with-resources

According to doc of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close() ,

> When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if
>   one exists, is also closed.

But accoring to [Must JDBC Resultsets and Statements be closed separately although the Connection is closed afterwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection) , it is seems to be a good practice to explicitly close `Connection` `Statement` and `ResultSet` .

If we still need to close `ResultSet`, we may need to have a nested try-with-resources statement since we may probably set parameter for `Statement` like this:

```
try (Connection conn = connectionProvider.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql) {//resources of conn and pst

     setPrepareStatementParameter(pstmt, kvs);//need to set parameters, so I have to put ResultSet into another try-with-resources statement

     try (ResultSet res = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
                ..............

     }
}
```

---

### Question:

Does put the ResultSet into a separate try-with-resources statement worth anything since the doc states that closing `Statement` will close the ResultSet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example covers too limited a range of the interactions between Connections, Statements, and ResultSets. Consider the following:

```
try (Connection conn = connectionProvider.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);) {

     for (int i = 0; i < kvs.length; i++) {
         setPrepareStatementParameter(pstmt, kvs[i]);

         // do other stuff

         // Place the ResultSet in another try with resources
         // to ensure the previous iteration's ResultSet
         // is closed when the next iteration begins
         try (ResultSet res = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
             ..............

         }
     }
 }
```

In the above example, the PreparedStatement is parametrized and executed a `kvs.length` number of times within the for-loop. Imagine a case in which the parametrization process, for any reason, took a significant length of time. Note that closing the PreparedStatement would do us no good since we want to reuse the compiled SQL statement at every iteration of the for-loop. Then surely nesting the ResultSet into its own try-with-resources block---thus ensuring the prior iteration's ResultSet is closed but the PreparedStatement remains open---is a worthwhile effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should close or put a try-resources for result set.

Why?

I quote what I've read from other answer that makes a lot of sense for me.

> - In theory closing the statement closes the result set.
> - In practice, some faulty JDBC driver implementations failed to do so.

Check the full answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133734/401529