# Release open Connection in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, database-connection, try-catch-finally, try-with-resources

I have a JSP/Servlet based application, the database team is complaining about the increase in open database connection.I suspect that the connection is not closed after use.

I want to make some code changes by initializing the connection string in try catch block as suggested in Java 8

I have tried closing the connection in final block which is working fine

here is the code i want to implement , Will this fix the issue?Is there any other way to close the open connections after use with little code change?

```
   try(Connection con =  DBConnectivity.openConnectionThread(); 
   PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1)) {
   -----
     ------
    }
```

Comment: Is this *THE ONLY PLACE* in your code that you access database? You don't use db in other part of the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try / Try-with-resources and Connection, Statement and ResultSet closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671697/try-try-with-resources-and-connection-statement-and-resultset-closing)

Comment: No there are multiple places where the connection is initialized. I am using Connection Pooling  

 public static final ThreadLocal<Connection> connectionThread = new ThreadLocal<Connection>();

Comment: @BipinSasi That is not a proper way of connection pooling, and can easily leak connections.

Answer (score 1):

You should close also [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

```
try(Connection con =  DBConnectivity.openConnectionThread();
     PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1)) 
    {
   -----
     ------
    }
```